# How to define a macro with API check?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to define a macro who calls an API available in iOS 11 only. I made every effort but failed. Here is my code.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_11_0
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    #define KNGTUtilIsIPhoneX [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.safeAreaInsets.top > 0
} else {
    #define KNGTUtilIsIPhoneX NO
}
#else
#define KNGTUtilIsIPhoneX NO
#endif
```

It seems a macro can only be defined in top level scope. So my code can't be compiled. If I don't use `@available`, the compiler will warn me with the following message.

> 'safeAreaInsets' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Please help me to find an elegant solution. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Macros are never an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write a function to call api and define this function. For example, with your code i can rewrite.

```
#define KNGTUtilIsIPhoneX isIphoneX()

BOOL isIphoneX() {
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    return [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.safeAreaInsets.top > 0;
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definition:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Usage:

```
  if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {

  }
```